# Table column combine

Tags: tables, formatting

[image]
I want to create a table of the following format. How do I combine the two columns CD into A and EF into B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `multicolumn`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{B}\\\hline
C&D&E&F\\\hline
1&2&3&4\\\hline
5&6&7&8\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```